# AngularJS: Ng:init - как присвоить динамический ng:model?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Всем привет. Имеется ng:repeat, создаваемый посредством json (methods), внутри него создаётся ряд радио-кнопок, которым присуща итерация (method).

Ниже, мне необходимо создать переменную, в которой будет лежать method выбранной радио-кнопки, для использования в дальнейшем. Набросаю шаблон для ясности.

```html
<li ng:repeat="method in methods">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng:model="$parent.deliveryMethod" ng:value="method" />
  </label>
</li>

<table ng:init="myValue = deliveryMethod.price | format">
  <tr>
    <td ng:bind="myValue"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Надеюсь суть ясна. Проблема в том, что как я понял, ng:init срабатывает раньше, чем успевает сформироваться methods.

Как быть?
Спасибо.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Покажите пожалуйста json `methods` . А также поясните более подробно, что Вам необходимо? Если записать в `deliveryMethod` значение `method`, то он и так там будет.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно просто показывать выбранный элемент из массива `methods` в другом месте.

Посмотрите пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/xf7nsaaL/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.methods = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "1",
      price:100
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "2",
      price:200
    }];
    $scope.deliveryMethod ={method:null};
    $scope.deliveryMethod2 ={myValue:null,method:null};
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <h3>
    Пример без переменной
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng:repeat="method in methods">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="method" ng:model="deliveryMethod.method" ng-value="method" />{{method.name}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td ng:bind="deliveryMethod.method.price | currency"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>
    Пример с переменной
    </h3>
     <ul>
      <li ng:repeat="method in methods">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="method2" ng:model="deliveryMethod2.method" ng-change="deliveryMethod2.myValue = (method.price | currency)" ng-value="method" />{{method.name}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td ng:bind="deliveryMethod2.myValue"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```